# Spring data query with parameters

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have to create this N1QL couchbase query in Spring data

```
select... LIKE "TASK:100:%"
```

where 100 is a parameter, but I don't know if it is possible

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where META().id like \"TASK:$1%:\" ")
List<Task> findTasks(String taskId);
```

Comment: I am not clear what the question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be the following:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where META().id like ('TASK:' || $1 || '%') ")
List<Task> findTasks(String taskId);
```

Although I think you should concatenate the id on the backend instead of inside the query.